# Direction of cross product of two vectors

Tags: vectors

Are there several ways to find the direction of a×b other than right hand thumb rule?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133288/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480343/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other rules which are identical to the Right Hand Thumb-rule.

A few are

> Cork-screw Rule
>   Right-hand mug rule